# Hidden text in column for sorting

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I am using "tablesorter" to handle my table sorting.

One of my columns is a checkbox or a cross, using 'glyphicons' in Bootstrap:

```
<td data-active="@m.is_active"><span class="glyphicon @(m.is_active ? "glyphicon-ok good_colour" : "glyphicon-remove bad_colour")"> </span></td>
```

But this doesn't work. I was hoping adding a data- attribute to the cell, it might work, but nope. Is there a way to add a hidden field to the cell that has to icon, to enable sorting? At the moment, it doesn't change, as there is no text in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Add a hidden span in the cell:

```
<td><span class="hidden">@m.is_active</span><span class="glyphicon @(m.is_active ? "glyphicon-ok good_colour" : "glyphicon-remove bad_colour")"> </span></td>
```